# Countdown timer rstarts from 24hrs when it reaches zero

Tags: javascript, php

I developed a computer based testing system where students can test their knowledge with countdown timer. I used the following codes which relate to the server very well.

first_page.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $get_time="select * from tests";
    $run_time = mysqli_query($con, $get_time);
    $row_time=mysqli_fetch_array($run_time);
    $duration=$row_time['duration'];

    $_SESSION["duration"]=$duration;
    $_SESSION["start_time"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $end_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION['duration'].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION['start_time'])));
    $_SESSION['end_time']=$end_time
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="second_page.php";
</script>
```

second_page.php

```
<div id="response"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     },1000);
</script>
```

response.php

```
session_start();
$from_time1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1=$_SESSION['end_time'];

$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);
$differenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;
echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceinseconds);
```

The problem now is that when the timer gets to zero, it goes to 24hrs and start counting down. Is there a way to amend these codes so that when the timer gets to zero it stops and redirects the user to a different page where I can say “You have used up your time and your answers have been submitted automatically”?

Comment: I recommend just using `time()` to do your calculations.

Comment: How to do that @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check in your response callback, something like this:

```
if (xmlhttp !== '0 minutes') {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
    window.location = 'put your url here';
}
```

When looking at your code i saw you do a request every 1 second. That is really bad practise, the server load with multiple clients will be enormous. Cant you return a date with PHP and do the countdown in javascript? And re-check every 5 minutes if javascript is still in sync with the date from php? from (60 * 60 * 24) request you go to (20 * 24) request per day per client.

Comment: Thanks Jasper for your response. I don't know javascript that much that is why I use PHP. I would appreciate if you can use my code to show me what you mean. Moreover the solution you gave above does not stop the counter from going to 24hrs when it gets to zero.